# How can I fetch age-restricted page using generic app token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I fetch age-restricted page using generic app token ?

Here is how I get app token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1237603453455381&client_secret=3539257a5231e337bb26d110bfb5e500&grant_type=client_credentials
```

But when I attempt to call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/60409543921?access_token=1237603453455381|H4PkFBu2PlSzHHMLPvHcSt8Y9Os
```

I get error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request.",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

Is there workaround against it other than using my personal token on server ?

Comment: What language are you using to fetch the data?

Comment: _“How can I fetch age-restricted page using generic app token ?”_ – you can’t, of course. That’s what the age restriction is for – to ensure content is only shown to people that fit the criteria. And therefor you have to use a user access token of a user that is allowed to see that content. (Unless it’s your own page, and you can get a page access token.)